# Get fetched web page data as a byte array using UnityWebRequest

Tags: unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

So the problem I have is that I don't know how can I get the fetched web page data as a byte array using UnityWebRequest since my WWW is obsolete right now.

For now it looks like that

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The unitywebrequest documentation is very comprehensive. What specifically did you struggle with